# Can I store the 'alias' info when I use SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, alias

I have a script that parses xml file to generate SQLite table automatically. And, the simplified command is as follows.

```
Table string CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS benchmark (id integer primary key autoincrement,Version float, CompilationParameters_Family text, CompilationParameters_XilinxVersion text, CompilationParameters_Device text, CompilationParameters_XilinxParameterList_Parameter_OptimizationGoal text, CompilationParameters_XilinxParameterList_Parameter_PlacerEffortLevel text)
```

It works well, but I wonder if I can attach some aliases for the long name in a  database.

Is this possible? I mean, can I have a command something like

```
Table string ... CompilationParameters_XilinxVersion tex >>as version<< ...
```

so that I can use **CompilationParameters_XilinxVersion** or **version** when retrieve the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible in SQL. However, you may want to create a [`VIEW`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) that simply substitutes the long column names with your short column aliases. Note that `VIEW`s in sqlite [are read-only](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html) and therefore cannot be written to.